# How make azure chat bot v4 works in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, azure, internet-explorer, chatbot

I have developed an Azure chat bot v4 and with Chrome and others browser it is works but not in Internet Explorer (I'm using IE11), the component is showed but not the chat text.

I have already added the library https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat-es5.js, it seems to work but if I write something the text isn't showed (but it calls https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/... every time I wrote something and the call returns a 200, so it seems to work but no...)

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    ...
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat-es5.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header class="header">
                ...
            </header>
            <div id="webchat" class="botChat" role="main"></div>
        </div>
        <script  type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            var styleOptions = {
                bubbleBackground: 'rgba(217, 229, 244, 1)',
                bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(250, 230, 238, 1)',
                rootWidth: '100%',
                innerWidth: '80%',
            };

            var botConnection = new window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                token: "mytoken"
            });

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
                directLine: botConnection,
                styleOptions: styleOptions
            }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
        </script>
    </body>
```

Why I don't see the text? (only on IE)

Comment: Check the JavaScript Console in Developer Tools (F12), any hints in there?

Comment: no errors in Console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had tested the issue and found that we can reproduce issue in IE 11 using Web Chat V4.

To fix it, you can try to explicitly specify height and width property for div container , like below.

```
<div id="webchat">

<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%
    }

    body {
        margin: 0
    }

    #webchat {
        height: 500px;
        width: 380px;
    }
</style>
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is a strange behaviour, I had min-height: 500px; max-height: 100%; but it needs an height property...